# Object to json string in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a problem with node.js to object to json string

```
var chat = {};
chat.messages = [];
chat.messages['en'] = [];
chat.messages['fr'] = [];
console.log(chat.messages)
console.log(JSON.stringify(chat.messages));
```

I got

```
[ en: [], fr: [] ]
[]
```

I don't know why this is not correctly convert

Comment: I just took a look in my crystal ball, and it says it's not correctly converted because you did'nt feed it the right data ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On this line, you initialize `chat.messages` as an empty array:

```
chat.messages = [];
```

Here, you use it as an object:

```
chat.messages['en'] = [];
chat.messages['fr'] = [];
```

These lines actually set properties on the array instance. It's curious that Node would include these properties in the normal `.toString()` result (i.e., that you'd see the set properties as elements of the array on `console.log(chat.messages)`.

---

In any case, to fix, declare `chat.messages` as an object:

```
chat.messages = {};
chat.messages['en'] = [];
chat.messages['fr'] = [];
```